# How compute $\int_0^t 1_{\{\zeta _s\in \Delta \}}ds$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $\zeta _s=(\xi^0_s,\xi^1_s)$ where $\xi^i_s$ are Markov process talking there value in $\mathbb Z^d$ and $P_s-$Measurable. The measure for $\zeta _s$ is $$\mathbb P_s^{(2)}((i,j),(k,l))=\mathbb P_s(i,k)\mathbb P_s(j,l).$$
How would you compute
$$\int_0^t1_{\{\zeta _s\in \Delta\} }ds$$
where $\Delta =\{i,j\in\mathbb Z^d\mid i=j\}$ ?

To me it's $$\int_0^t1_{\{\zeta _s\in \Delta\} }ds=\mathbb P^{(2)}(\zeta _s\in \Delta \mid s\in [0,t]),$$
but how can I do better ?

Comment: What do you mean by "computing" a random variable?

Comment: If I would ask the expectation of $\int_0^t...$, would it be better ?

Comment: At least, you would be asking for a *number*, yes.

Comment: Ok, great. In fact it's what I would like to compute. Any idea ? @Did

Comment: Sure, plenty. You first.

Comment: @Did: May be $$\mathbb E[\int...]\underset{Fubini}{=}\int_0^t\mathbb E[1_{\zeta _s\in \Delta }]ds=\int_0^t \mathbb P^{(2)}(\zeta _s\in \Delta \mid s\in [0,t])ds$$ but I don't know how to continue.